# How do I deploy a python wheels package statically on a custom CDN server?

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel, pypiserver

I have a fork of a CPython extension package that takes literally hours to compile, so I would like to deploy precompiled wheels somewhere to download from instead of compiling from source.

I am also aware that I can host `pypiserver` myself, but I have CDN service I have lying around for basically free, and I wonder if I can deploy wheels somehow "statically" on my CDN and then do:

```
pip install -i https://<my cdn of choice> SomePackage
```

instead of:

```
pip install https://<my cdn of choice>/SomePackage-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

which would allow me to specify the package version or operating system.

Meaning the "repository" in that case would be just a folder with bunch of static files in right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a 'simple' index at the root of your CDN, and make the file structure for each project equivalent to what `pip` expects for a 'simple' index, which is essentially:

```
simple
├── SomePackage
│   ├── SomePackage-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
│   └── index.html
└── index.html
```

And then you can do:

```
$ pip install -i https://<my cdn of choice>/simple SomePackage
```

See [PEP 503 -- Simple Repository API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/) for the exact specification of how the HTML pages should be structured.